# Appending element inside appended element not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am making a change password module where on click of edit-password button a modal shows-up where Old/current password form gets appended to modal-body where a user has to insert his current password on correct password entered, the new-password form gets appended to modal-body. On click of new password submit button its 1st job is to checks if the length of the password is less than 7 characters, if its true a span with a message gets appended to the submit-button id of new password form. But it's not appending span element to an already appended element i.e. the new password form.

I am new to jquery/Laravel, don't know why this is not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        function show_old_password_modal(){
            $("#editModal").show();
            $("#modalBody , .modal-title").html("");
            $(".modal-title").append("Enter Old Password");
            $("#modalBody").append("<form method='POST'>"+
                                        "<div class='form-inline'>"+
                                            "<label for='oldPassword'>Old Password: </label> &nbsp;&nbsp;"+
                                            "<input type='password' id='oldPassword' class='form-control col-lg-6'>"+
                                        "</div> "+
                                        "<br>"+
                                        "<span class='badge badge-danger' id='spanDanger' ></span>"+ 
                                        "<br>"+
                                        "<input type='submit' id='oldPasswordSubmit' class='btn btn-success update-btn' value='Submit'> "+
                                    "</form>");
        }

        $("#edit-password").click(function(){
            show_old_password_modal();
        });

        $(document).on("click","#oldPasswordSubmit", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var userId = "{{ Auth::user()->id }}";
            console.log(userId);
            var oldPassword = $("#oldPassword").val();
            console.log(oldPassword);
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('check.old.password') }}",
                message: "GET",
                data: { userId : userId , oldPassword : oldPassword },
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data.result);
                    if(data.result == 1){
                        $("#modalBody , .modal-title").html("");
                        $(".modal-title").append("Enter New Password");
                        $("#modalBody").append("<form method='POST'>"+
                                                    "<div class='form-inline'>"+
                                                        "<label for='newPassword'>New Password: </label> &nbsp;&nbsp;"+
                                                        "<input type='password' id='newPassword' class='form-control col-lg-6'>"+
                                                    "</div> "+
                                                    "<br>"+
                                                    "<input type='submit' id='newPasswordSubmit' class='btn btn-success update-btn' value='Submit'> "+ 
                                                "</form>");
                    }
                    else{
                        show_old_password_modal();
                        $("#spanDanger").text("Invalid Old Password");
                    }    
                },
                error: function(error){
                    console.log(error.responseText);
                }
            });
        });

        $(document).on("click","#newPasswordSubmit",function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var userId = "{{ Auth::id() }}"
            console.log("userId: "+userId);
            var newPassword = $("#newPassword").val();
            console.log("newPass: "+newPassword);
            if(newPassword.length < 7){
                //$("#spanA").html("Password length should be greater than 6");
                $("#newPasswordSubmit").append("<span class='badge badge-danger'>Password length should be greater than 6</span>");
                return;
            }
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ url('/editProfile/password?_method=PUT') }}",
                method: "POST",
                data: { userId : userId , newPassword : newPassword },
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    $("#editModal").hide();
                    message(data.message , data.status);
                },
                error: function(error){
                    console.log(error.responseText);
                }
            });
        });

            $("#closeModal").click(function(){
                $("#editModal").hide();
            });
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="modal" id="editModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
          
                <!-- Modal Header -->
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                  <button type="button" class="close" id="closeModal" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
          
                <!-- Modal body -->
                <div class="modal-body" id="modalBody">
                  
                </div>
          
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h1 class="col-lg-6 text-center">Profile</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="card col-lg-6">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="name">
                        <label for="name">Name: </label>
                        <b id="showName"></b>
                        <a type="button" id="edit-name" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-right">Edit</a>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="email">
                        <label for="email">Email: </label>
                        <b id="showEmail"></b>
                        <a type="button" id="edit-email" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-right">Edit</a>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="password">
                        <label for="passsword">Password: </label>
                        <b>*********</b>
                        <a type="button" id="edit-password" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-right">Edit</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card offset-lg-2 col-lg-4 h-25" id="message">
                <div class="card-body" id="msgCardBody">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you  were appending your error message to input-box that's not possible. You can append `span` to some div i.e : `<div class='newPasswordSubmit'></div>` here using `$(".newPasswordSubmit").html..` will append your error message below your input box.

**Demo Code**(I have remove ajax code and some other code ) :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function show_old_password_modal() {
    $("#editModal").show();
    $("#modalBody , .modal-title").html("");
    $(".modal-title").append("Enter Old Password");
    $("#modalBody").append("<form method='POST'>" +
      "<div class='form-inline'>" +
      "<label for='oldPassword'>Old Password: </label> &nbsp;&nbsp;" +
      "<input type='password' id='oldPassword' class='form-control col-lg-6'>" +
      "</div> " +
      "<br>" +
      "<span class='badge badge-danger' id='spanDanger' ></span>" +
      "<br>" +
      "<input type='submit' id='oldPasswordSubmit' class='btn btn-success update-btn' value='Submit'> " +
      "</form>");
  }

  $("#edit-password").click(function() {
    show_old_password_modal();
  });

  $(document).on("click", "#oldPasswordSubmit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var userId = "{{ Auth::user()->id }}";
    console.log(userId);
    var oldPassword = $("#oldPassword").val();
    console.log(oldPassword);
 
          $("#modalBody , .modal-title").html("");
          $(".modal-title").append("Enter New Password");
          $("#modalBody").append("<form method='POST'>" +
            "<div class='form-inline'>" +
            "<label for='newPassword'>New Password: </label> &nbsp;&nbsp;" +
            "<input type='password' id='newPassword' class='form-control col-lg-6'>" +
            "</div> " +
            "<br>" +
            "<input type='submit' id='newPasswordSubmit' class='btn btn-success update-btn' value='Submit'> <div class='newPasswordSubmit'></div>" +
            "</form>"); //<--adding <div></div>
       
  });

  $(document).on("click", "#newPasswordSubmit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var userId = "{{ Auth::id() }}"
    console.log("userId: " + userId);
    var newPassword = $("#newPassword").val();
    console.log("newPass: " + newPassword);
    if (newPassword.length < 7) {
      //$("#spanA").html("Password length should be greater than 6");
    //change to class
      $(".newPasswordSubmit").html("<span class='badge badge-danger'>Password length should be greater than 6</span>");
      return;
    }else{
      $(".newPasswordSubmit").html('');//remove span if condtion false
   console.log("go done")
   }
  });

  $("#closeModal").click(function() {
    $("#editModal").hide();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="modal" id="editModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" id="closeModal" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body" id="modalBody">

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1 class="col-lg-6 text-center">Profile</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card col-lg-6">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="name">
          <label for="name">Name: </label>
          <b id="showName"></b>
          <a type="button" id="edit-name" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-right">Edit</a>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="email">
          <label for="email">Email: </label>
          <b id="showEmail"></b>
          <a type="button" id="edit-email" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-right">Edit</a>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="password">
          <label for="passsword">Password: </label>
          <b>*********</b>
          <a type="button" id="edit-password" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-right">Edit</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card offset-lg-2 col-lg-4 h-25" id="message">
      <div class="card-body" id="msgCardBody">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Even I tried this and was successful but my original question is why can't one append an entire span/div tag with text attributes in it to an already appended element. In my case the new password form with its input field and submit button is appended in modal-body so why can't I just append a new div/span element below it?

Comment: because when you used append the element which you are appending add inside some other element.And in your code you are appending `span` to your `input` i.e : `<input..><span>..</input>` <--this is not possible you  can only append to some `div,p,h1..` etc.Have a look for more info about [append](https://api.jquery.com/append/).

Comment: Ok so u mean to say is that the span gets append to input i.e. <input> <span>..</span> </input>. But the append() method inserts specified content at the end of the selected elements so here how does it ends up between input tag ?

Comment: It append the specified content as the last child of each element .Please read that page to get more information about `append` method.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        function show_old_password_modal(){
            $("#editModal").show();
            $("#modalBody , .modal-title").html("");
            $(".modal-title").append("Enter Old Password");
            $("#modalBody").append("<form method='POST'>"+
                                        "<div class='form-inline'>"+
                                            "<label for='oldPassword'>Old Password: </label> &nbsp;&nbsp;"+
                                            "<input type='password' id='oldPassword' class='form-control col-lg-6'>"+
                                        "</div> "+
                                        "<br>"+
                                        "<span class='badge badge-danger' id='spanDanger' ></span>"+ 
                                        "<br>"+
                                        "<input type='submit' id='oldPasswordSubmit' class='btn btn-success update-btn' value='Submit'> "+
                                    "</form>");
        }

        $("#edit-password").click(function(){
            show_old_password_modal();
        });

        $(document).on("click","#oldPasswordSubmit", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var userId = "{{ Auth::user()->id }}";
            console.log(userId);
            var oldPassword = $("#oldPassword").val();
            console.log(oldPassword.length); 
            $("#oldPasswordSubmit").parent().find('.badge').remove(); 
                        if(oldPassword.length < 7){
                //$("#spanA").html("Password length should be greater than 6");               
                $("#oldPasswordSubmit").after("<span class='badge badge-danger'>Password length should be greater than 6</span>");
                return;
            }
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('check.old.password') }}",
                message: "GET",
                data: { userId : userId , oldPassword : oldPassword },
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data.result);
                    if(data.result == 1){
                        $("#modalBody , .modal-title").html("");
                        $(".modal-title").append("Enter New Password");
                        $("#modalBody").append("<form method='POST'>"+
                                                    "<div class='form-inline'>"+
                                                        "<label for='newPassword'>New Password: </label> &nbsp;&nbsp;"+
                                                        "<input type='password' id='newPassword' class='form-control col-lg-6'>"+
                                                    "</div> "+
                                                    "<br>"+
                                                    "<input type='submit' id='newPasswordSubmit' class='btn btn-success update-btn' value='Submit'> "+ 
                                                "</form>");
                    }
                    else{
                        show_old_password_modal();
                        $("#spanDanger").text("Invalid Old Password");
                    }    
                },
                error: function(error){
                    console.log(error.responseText);
                }
            });
        });

        $(document).on("click","#newPasswordSubmit",function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var userId = "{{ Auth::id() }}"
            console.log("userId: "+userId);
            var newPassword = $("#newPassword").val();
            console.log("newPass: "+newPassword.length);
            if(newPassword.length < 7){
                //$("#spanA").html("Password length should be greater than 6");
                $("#newPasswordSubmit").append("<span class='badge badge-danger'>Password length should be greater than 6</span>");
                return;
            }
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ url('/editProfile/password?_method=PUT') }}",
                method: "POST",
                data: { userId : userId , newPassword : newPassword },
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    $("#editModal").hide();
                    message(data.message , data.status);
                },
                error: function(error){
                    console.log(error.responseText);
                }
            });
        });

            $("#closeModal").click(function(){
                $("#editModal").hide();
            });

    });
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="modal" id="editModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">

                <!-- Modal Header -->
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                  <button type="button" class="close" id="closeModal" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>

                <!-- Modal body -->
                <div class="modal-body" id="modalBody">

                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h1 class="col-lg-6 text-center">Profile</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="card col-lg-6">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="name">
                        <label for="name">Name: </label>
                        <b id="showName"></b>
                        <a type="button" id="edit-name" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-right">Edit</a>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="email">
                        <label for="email">Email: </label>
                        <b id="showEmail"></b>
                        <a type="button" id="edit-email" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-right">Edit</a>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="password">
                        <label for="passsword">Password: </label>
                        <b>*********</b>
                        <a type="button" id="edit-password" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-right">Edit</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card offset-lg-2 col-lg-4 h-25" id="message">
                <div class="card-body" id="msgCardBody">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```